# Where is the capital gains tax defined in the law?

Tags: united-states, tax-law

Which law defines the fact that the capital gains tax is taxed at a different rate than the income tax? I know 26 U.S. Code Subchapter P defines what capital assets are and what capital gains and capital losses are, but I'm not sure where it's defined that capital assets are taxed differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like it's in [26 USC 1](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/1) (h), which explains how tax is to be computed on capital gains.